# Nuxt: TypeError: blogRoutes is not iterable

Tags: nuxt.js, netlify

I'm testing out Nuxt, specifically, how to generate routes for static site mode. When I deploy to Netlify I get the error `TypeError: blogRoutes is not iterable` in the deploy logs. What does this mean as it seems the output of both requests are arrays of simple strings. Any help would be greatly appreciated .

Below is a slightly contrived example as I'm making two calls to Contentful, in reality this will be to Shopify and Contentful.

```
generate: {
    routes: () => {
        const client = contentful.createClient(config)

        const blogRoutes = client
            .getEntries({
                content_type: 'blogPost'
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.items.map(
                    entry => `/blog/${entry.fields.slug}`
                )
            })
        const collectionRoutes = client
            .getEntries({
                content_type: 'collection'
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.items.map(
                    entry => `/collections/${entry.fields.slug}`
                )
            })
        const routes = [[...blogRoutes, ...collectionRoutes]]

        return routes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`blogRoutes` and `collectionRoutes` are both promises, not arrays.  They resolve into arrays (I'm assuming), but you need to either await them, or use Promise.all().

Also note that it looks like you're not returning the right [data](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate#routes), you want to return an array of strings, not and array of an array of strings.

```
generate: {
    routes: async () => { // add async here
        const client = contentful.createClient(config)

        const blogRoutes = await client // add await here
            .getEntries({
                content_type: 'blogPost'
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.items.map(
                    entry => `/blog/${entry.fields.slug}`
                )
            })
        const collectionRoutes = await client // add await here
            .getEntries({
                content_type: 'collection'
            })
            .then(response => {
                return response.items.map(
                    entry => `/collections/${entry.fields.slug}`
                )
            })

        const routes = [...blogRoutes, ...collectionRoutes] // return a single array of strings

        return routes
    }
}
```